# Bind ListView SelectedItem Column MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, selecteditem

I have the following XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Franchises, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFranchise, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" Height="150">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="FranchiseID" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FranchiseID}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Franchise Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FranchiseName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And I want to pass the `FranchiseID` to my `Presenter` View Model `SelectedFranchise` value.

`Presenter` ViewModel

```
public class Presenter : ObservableObject
{

    private DataView _Franchises = Controller.BaseballDB.Tables["Franchise"].DefaultView;
    private long _SelectedFranchise;

    public DataView Franchises
    {
        get
        {
            Controller.Refresh();
            _Franchises = Controller.BaseballDB.Tables["Franchise"].DefaultView;
            return _Franchises;
        }
        set
        {
            Controller.Refresh();
            _Franchises = Controller.BaseballDB.Tables["Franchise"].DefaultView;
            RaisePropertyChangeEvent("Franchises");
        }
    }

    public long SelectedFranchise
    {
        get { return _SelectedFranchise; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedFranchise = value;
            Debug.Print(_SelectedFranchise.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it's giving me an error, because it wants to pass the entire string of the Selected Item to the property. I've scoured the web, but apparently everyone wants to only select an item when there's only one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectedValuePath` with `SelectedValue`. Please make sure that DataType is same for `FranchiseID` and `SelectedFranchise`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Franchises, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="FranchiseID" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFranchise}" SelectionMode="Single" Height="150">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="FranchiseID" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FranchiseID}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Franchise Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FranchiseName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```